# How to auto-adjust the image height and length based on needs

Tags: c#, winforms, image, bitmap

I have a piece of code that generates the barcode image (using the `Free 3 of 9` font); nevertheless, the picture size is defined ahead of time and I am wondering what can I do to adjust it to the required size?

```
   private static Bitmap CreateBarcode(string code)
    {
        var myBitmap = new Bitmap(500, 50);
        //var myBitmap = new Bitmap();
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
        var jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        var strFormat = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center };
        g.DrawString(code, new Font("Free 3 of 9", 50), Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 0, 500, 50), strFormat);
    var myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
    var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

    var myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
    return myBitmap;
}

private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{
    var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
    foreach (var codec in codecs)
    {
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
        {
            return codec;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just supply the required size of the image in the function at the time of BarCOde generation?

Comment: that is what I ended up doing - counted the longest number of characters in each string and multiplied it to the font size; same way for height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `Graphics.MeasureString` method. This will measure the size of the resulting image representation of the string you're drawing, allowing you to calculate the size of your bitmap. If it doesn't fit, grow the bitmap before drawing, or if it's too small crop it. [MSDN for `Measure String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)